# How to create facebook app to sell products of Magento store in Facebook Store from scratch?

Tags: php, facebook, e-commerce, magento-1.7

I want to create a facebook store to sell my products via facebook. There is many facebook applications available for creating store application in Facebook. But they charge subscription fee and their logo banner in my store. So I want to create a facebook store app from scratch. These are some sites offering facebook store creation:

http://storefrontsocial.com/

http://www.apptha.com/category/extension/Magento/Magento-Facebook-App

http://www.storeya.com/etsy

Is it possible to create a facebook store without the help of these kind of service provider websites ? If yes, Please send me the tutorial URLs or sample codes here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution from this URL: http://simpleecode.com/magento-facebook-store-integration/
Nice tutorial and the author provided source code with the tutorial. Explained each block in the application.

I developed like below:

1. Create a facebook business page to link with your app, the Page must be categorized as an "App Page" (found under "Brands & Products") and the Page name must contain your app name.
2. Create a facebook app and configure your page that you listed products from magento store as mentioned in the tutorial link. then link the store page and app together , you can find this section "App details" [image]. Select existing facebook option to set your facebook page to the store.

Answer (score 0):

Hello First You need to make a site on your on host. After that go to facebook developer section and create developer ID.

Now simple you can do like :-

```
<body>
    <div id='fb-root'></div>
    <script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
    Select a Facebook Page(<a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php" target="_blank">create now?</a>):
    <p><a onclick='addToPage(); return false;'>Add to Page</a></p>
    <p id='msg'></p>

    <script> 
      FB.init({appId: "App_ID_passhere", status: true, cookie: true});

      function addToPage() {

        // calling the API ...
        var obj = {
          method: 'pagetab',
          redirect_uri: 'URL of Your Store',
        };

        FB.ui(obj);
      }

    </script>
```

Comment: I already have web store and facebook developer ID, and App ID secret ID. Could you explain the post in detail. This answer will be useful all who want to create facebook stores for their web stores.